# Azure Portal Application Settings for Container App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I'm not able to update the application settings in the Azure portal to override my .net core appsetting file.

I've been following the instructions from this MS doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/configure-common

I pushed my container from Azure Container Registry an azure app service (Windows OS)

My appsettings file looks like this (The value is empty as I always want to inject the value using the Azure Portal)

[image: AppSettings]

I have given the setting a value in the portal

[image: Portal settings]

The setting is not being picked up when I deploy the app. I have tried restarting a couple of times. I have checked in the Kudu console and can see the app setting there.

Just to add, further docs mention that this should work in web apps for containers - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#SetEnvVar
[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please remember this is not a overide operation. Actually, it will refer to `AppSettings` on portal after you publish to Azure.

Comment: Hi, have you solved this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you publish your app to Azure, it is no matter with your `.json` file. If you add the `key-value` in AppSettings, it is setted. So I guess it is wrong with your code of getting the `AppSettings` Value, that doesn't mean the `AppSettings` is not setted.

**And this is the Way of getting `AppSettings`(like "MyAppSetting": "12345"):**

```
var environmentmyDesiredKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyAppSetting");
```

This is what I set on the portal:

[image]

And with the code above, I can get the `AppSettings` successful.

[image]

Let me know if you have doubts.

Comment: I have accepted this answer. I also needed to add AddEnvironmentVariables(); to my ConfigurationBuilder.